# Scipy Bilinear Transformation

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

[image]

So I was trying to perform this bilinear transformation with scipy but the final result does not 
match the book

In the question T = 1/2 .Therefore fs = 1/T = 2 . Correct me if I am wrong

```
 import scipy.signal as s 

 z = s.bilinear([0.1,1],[16.01,0.2,1],2)

Result
 z = (array([0.0054272 , 0.00775314, 0.00232594]), array([ 1.        , -1.97829121,  0.99379749]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example from [bilinear's docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bilinear.html) one uses an [lti](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lti.html) object. The docs for the `lti` states that

> If (numerator, denominator) is passed in for *system, coefficients for both the numerator and denominator should be specified in descending exponent order (e.g., s^2 + 3s + 5 would be represented as [1, 3, 5]).

That's a hint, so the code would be

```
z = s.bilinear([1,0.1],[1,0.2,16.01],2)
print(z)
```

with reversed order of coefficients. The output is

```
(array([ 0.1249619,  0.0060957, -0.1188662]), array([1.00000000e+00, 6.09570253e-04, 9.51234380e-01]))
```

That is very close to the values are given in the book and the difference is almost sure due to the numerical calculus effects. However, I don't know why the output contains the coefficients in non-reversed order and I was not able to find extended info in the docs.